# Architecture for creating PDF files from Excel reports

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have 1 routine that is structured like this:

1. `C#` console C opens `xl` workbook A
2. C then runs A's macro M which saves the target worksheet as a PDF using VBA
3. C then uses `PDFsharp` to encrypt the PDF file.
4. C then emails this file.

Currently this procedure is for one report so no problem if the architecture isn't textbook.

I imagine in the future there may be many target worksheets in many different workbooks all going to lots of different recipients. If this is the case then Step 2 will need to go as I will not want to have to copy this `VBA` code into every target workbook! The only alternative I can imagine as my experience is limited is the following:

1. Take the current VBA code out of Excel and move it into C using a reference to `Excel.Interops`

Assuming that the target worksheets are the finished article i.e. no further manipulation is required before going to PDF is the above the correct approach for moving this step out of VBA and into the console, or should I create the PDF using a different library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least-effort option is moving the code from the worksheet into a VBA add-in by deleting all the sheets/data out and then use 'save as' to turn the workbook into an add-in which you can then load into excel and will be available all the time.  Depending on how you've written it some changes may be required but they won't be as big as a port to c#.

That said, having the code all in one place will make the whole process easier to look after in the future.  Plus you've already got C# code automating excel to fire the VBA so it may be better to do it now if you have time.

Comment: ...and using `Interops` is my only option? I can't save an Excel worksheet in C# using another method? Can I use something more generic to save as a PDF and then point that code at an Excel worksheet? Suppose I'm hoping to put something even more generic in place so if in the future someone said - "Can you please send out this Word document in PDF format" then I could just point my code at it aswell?!

Comment: I am using `interop` so I'll use that for the timebeing; suppose it makes sense _`if making a pdf from xl then use the xl interop`_

Comment: in terms of Excle add-ins I've created them before but asthe console is controlling a lot of the process already I'm keen to move as much functionality in there as possible

Comment: @whytheq Whichever way you go (vba addin or c# port) part 1 & 2 of your requirements are 'open a file in Excel and do stuff with it' and that requires COM Interop of some kind.

You can avoid referencing an Excel specific interop library using 'Late Binding' but at some point you have to pass a message to Excel to make it do something - be that fire a macro (which could be in an addin) and quit as you do today or something more specific.